# How to set a default handler in django fobi

Tags: django

Did anyone managed to set a default handler in django-fobi? What was the approach? I'd like to set the db_store handler as a default for all of the forms.

I've tried to set defaults in models but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no out-of-box solution for that.

However, you could do as follows:

**Solution 1:**

Using django signals, watch updates of the `FormEntry` model and add the db_handler plugin programmatically each time a form is saved (it it doesn't yet have it assigned).

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save)
def update_document(sender, **kwargs):
    app_label = sender._meta.app_label
    model_name = sender._meta.model_name.lower()
    instance = kwargs['instance']

    if app_label == 'fobi' and model_name == 'formentry':
        from fobi.models import FormHandlerEntry
        FormHandlerEntry.objects.get_or_create(
            plugin_uid='db_store',
            form_entry=instance     
        )
```

**Solution 2:**

You could also register a form callback (fobi has callbacks implemented for almost each stage of form submission process).

In your callback you would have to mimic the functionality of the `db_store` plugin (copy-paste mainly).

```
import datetime

import simplejson as json

from fobi.base import (
    form_callback_registry,
    FormCallback,
    get_processed_form_data,
)
from fobi.constants import CALLBACK_FORM_VALID
from fobi.contrib.plugins.form_handlers.db_store.models import SavedFormDataEntry


class AutoDbStore(FormCallback):

    stage = CALLBACK_FORM_VALID

    def callback(self, form_entry, request, form):
        form_element_entries = form_entry.formelemententry_set.all()

        # Clean up the values, leave our content fields and empty values.
        field_name_to_label_map, cleaned_data = get_processed_form_data(
            form,
            form_element_entries
        )

        for key, value in cleaned_data.items():
            if isinstance(value, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date)):
                cleaned_data[key] = value.isoformat() \
                    if hasattr(value, 'isoformat') \
                    else value

        saved_form_data_entry = SavedFormDataEntry(
            form_entry=form_entry,
            user=request.user if request.user and request.user.pk else None,
            form_data_headers=json.dumps(field_name_to_label_map),
            saved_data=json.dumps(cleaned_data)
        )
        saved_form_data_entry.save()


form_callback_registry.register(AutoDbStore)
```